# Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined at Object.renderGraphiQL

Tags: express-graphql, graphiql

i was going through a GraphQL tutorial from udemy,

https://www.udemy.com/introduction-to-graphql-and-apollo-building-modern-apis

And i was going through the guide to operating graphql and graphiql -> apollo -express - server. And got this. This particular error has not been defined in the videos. It is a free tutorial and lecture 9 has this.
Wht to do. i find no solution. Please help.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
at Object.renderGraphiQL (/home/dell/Desktop/graphql- 
tutorial/node_modules/apollo-server-module- 
graphiql/src/renderGraphiQL.ts:48:17)
at Object. (/home/dell/Desktop/graphql-tutorial/node_modules/apollo- 
server-module-graphiql/src/resolveGraphiQLString.ts:62:10)
at step (/home/dell/Desktop/graphql-tutorial/node_modules/apollo- 
server-module-graphiql/dist/resolveGraphiQLString.js:32:23)
at Object.next (/home/dell/Desktop/graphql- 
tutorial/node_modules/apollo-server-module- 
graphiql/dist/resolveGraphiQLString.js:13:53)
at fulfilled (/home/dell/Desktop/graphql-tutorial/node_modules/apollo- 
server-module-graphiql/dist/resolveGraphiQLString.js:4:58)
 at 
 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

**renderGraphiQLString.js**

This is the line it says has error -->

```
 export function renderGraphiQL(data: GraphiQLData): string {
 const endpointURL = data.endpointURL;
 const endpointWs =
  endpointURL.startsWith('ws://') || endpointURL.startsWith('wss://');
  const subscriptionsEndpoint = data.subscriptionsEndpoint;
  const usingHttp = !endpointWs;
  const usingWs = endpointWs || !!subscriptionsEndpoint;
  const endpointURLWs =
  usingWs && (endpointWs ? endpointURL : subscriptionsEndpoint);
```

**resolveGraphiQLString.js**

```
 export async function resolveGraphiQLString(
 query: any = {},
 options: GraphiQLData | Function,
  ...args
  ): Promise<string> {
  const graphiqlParams = createGraphiQLParams(query);
  const graphiqlOptions = await resolveGraphiQLOptions(options, 
  ...args);
   const graphiqlData = createGraphiQLData(graphiqlParams, 
   graphiqlOptions);
   return renderGraphiQL(graphiqlData);
  }
```

**server.js**

```
 import express  from 'express';
 import {graphqlExpress,graphiqlExpress} from 'apollo-server-express';
 import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
 import schema  from './schema.js'


  const server = express();

  server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress(schema));

  server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' 
   }));


 server.listen(4000,() =>{
 console.log('listening  on port 4000');
 });
```

Comment: I'm on the same step on the same tutorial and hit this exact issue!

Answer (score 6):

I was doing the same tutorial and got stuck with the same error. I just now got it working. For me, I had spelled `endpointURL` as `endpointUrl` because it seems stupid to me to capitalize acronyms within camel-case, but of course this being a specific key, it has to be spelled right.

For you, the only difference I see in the code is that I think you should pass `{schema}` to `graphqlExpress`, but you're passing just `schema`. So here's how I have it:

`server.use("/graphql", bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }))`

Comment: You save my day! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not correct. In order to define the graphiql endpoint you need to do this in the following way:

```
const server = express();
server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress(schema));
server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }));
```

Keep in mind you should pass to the graphiqlExpress method the endpointURL of your real graphql endpoint.

Cheers!

Comment: hi daneil...i have added the server.js file and  in it i have written your code. With this code ...(this i had written previously also).. i am getting the same error

Comment: It indeed does not work, Daniel Martinez should edit his answer